# Where would I ask questions about development-related books comparisons?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to buy one of the two books, [RabbitMQ Essentials](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JZMZ1PI) or [RabbitMQ in action](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935182978).

Is there a StackExhange site where I could ask for people for comparison?

Comment: Go read the Amazon reviews like everybody else.  Or buy both.

Comment: I didn't ask about a single book. I've asked about book comparisons. I don't think the other answer addresses *comparisons*, I've already checked that other answer.
What I need is an info from somebody who has read both books to tell me which one is better for my purpose. 
Thanks for the replies though.

Comment: I don't know how you'll survive, not finding someone who has read both books so they can tell you what direction to go in.  But I suspect you'll manage to find your way through this rough time.  Good luck and godspeed.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. One can tell you're very approachable person that embraces innocently any new question or idea without assuming the asker is lazy or something similar.

Comment: Why, thank you! It's rare that someone so lost in this big world of ours is still bright and sensitive enough to be able to see the good in others.  I will pray for you on this journey of discovery.

Comment: Heh, now I'm starting to like you with the stubbornes, humor, irony or whatever it is. On the serious side, there are websites on all kinds of crap these days. My question is whether there was one that **compared** books. It didn't ask for sarcasm or anything. But Internet is too big for me to argue with all of it, so you win.

Comment: *scoots backward across the office to my chalkboard*... *grabs bamboo stick with chalk on end*... *climbs step ladder*... *stretches out, adds one tickmark diagonally across a group of four vertical check marks, the last of thousands of such groups spanning yards of space on the board* One more internet argument won. *smug grin intensifies*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no Stack Exchange site where that question would be on-topic. The answers would be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I would say experience based, but isn't that also a trait of an expert?not sure why it has been penalized that much.